# Why is Parallelizable attribute not showing in my SpecFlow feature.cs files

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I'm using NUnitv3 with SpecFlow 2.0, ive added the attribute [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] to my assemblyinfo.cs and have regenerated all of the steps.

However what im noticing is this attribute is not being populated into the generated feature files.

A post by Gaspar Nagy here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Parallel-Execution
suggests that it should be. Could someone she light on how I can get this attribute included?

Answer (score 0):

This is an assembly level attribute. You need it only once. This is the "flag" that the NUnit Test Runner uses to determine if the tests supports parallelism.

SpecFlow 2.0 is not adding this attribute automatically to your code, so have to do it manually once.

Comment: ParallelizableAttribute mat be used at the Assembly, Class or method level - currently without effect at the method level. Putting it on the assembly works if all classes are equally capable of running in parallel.